# How would I programmatically call an object method? Like MyObject.XVariable(//some function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an object, that takes input from an API call to fill it up.

```
let MyDog = {
Name: 'Dog',
}
let arrayFunctions;
fetchDogsFunctions(dogAPIUrl).then(res => {
//results is an array that has a list of functions the dog has, like //getStats(), or walkDog()
arrayFunctions = res;
})
```

Now I want to map through the array results and call the function on my dog like...

```
arrayFunctions.map(item => {
 await MyDog.item(//Params)
})
```

How can I do this??

Where MyDog is set up from a file, and then depending on the array functions, for each function it programmatically fills in the call to the new function like MyDog.item where item is a variable in an array called "Walk()"

Comment: it is not clear what you want, why you are waiting to `MyDog` with `await` if it's `object` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed how your data might have structured. Pls take a look below and you might get the idea of how to call functions dynamically using "await"

```js
const MyDog = {
  funA(a) { return Promise.resolve('Function A called with parameter ' + a) }
  , funB(b) { return Promise.resolve('Function B called with parameter ' + b) }
}

const arrayFunctions = ['funA', 'funB']

Promise.all(arrayFunctions.map(async (item, i) => 
                 await MyDog[item](++i))
           )
.then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any property name "item" in your MyDog Object

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to do :

```
MyDog[item]()
```

within the loop.

I was asking the correct syntax to perform this operation